# Implementing auto restart of async code

Tags: c#, async-await

I have some long running code:

```
Action GetSomeAction()=> () => {
//some code that takes a long time...
};
```

I run it like this:

```
_currentTask = Task.Run(GetSomeAction());
```

I need to ensure it restarts if it throws an exception. At first, I wrote this:

```
async Task EnsureTaskExecution()
{
    try
    {
        await _currentTask;
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Log.Error($"task exception: {x.GetType()} : {x.Message} {x.StackTrace} {x.InnerException?.GetType()} {x.InnerException?.Message}.");
        //...?
    }
}
```

How do I properly restart it though? Inserting this into catch block seems like bad idea, since it introduces recursion:

```
_currentTask = Task.Run(GetSomeAction());
await EnsureTaskExecution();
```

Are there any better options? Is there recommended pattern for this? This seems like an almost trivial task, yet I can't find anything.

Comment: IIRC C# tasks are not restartable, so what you'd do instead is basically make it recursive if it fails for a recoverable reason

Comment: A Task is not a thread to be restarted. It's a promise that something will run and produce something in the future. There's no "restarting" just like there's no "re-calling" a method. If you want to call something again, call it again.

Comment: @servy I don't think this is a dupe of that as this is specific to async/await which has very different semantics

Comment: BTW `GetSomeAction` can be any method that returns `void`. It doesn't have to be a lambda. If you had a `void GetSomeAction(){}` that you wanted to run in the background you coudl write `Task.Run(()=>GetSomeAction());` or even `Task.Run(GetSomeAction);`

Comment: @Mgetz There are async solutions there, although you can use any of the synchronous solutions and just add in the one `await` of the asynchronous operation you have.  I have full confidence in their ability to add an `await` before the asynchronous method they're calling while everything else stays the same.  The fundamental approach to structuring retry logic isn't actually any different, and that's what's being asked about.

Comment: Have a look at a the [Polly reliability framework](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) - this way you can specify a retry policy when you invoke asynchronous methods.